# Multiple .shift() operations overwriting each other

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to only apply a shift to a certain subset of a dataframe? Currently the below will overwrite df['End'] because I assign it directly to df['End'], but I can't quite figure out how to only apply it to a smaller selection.

Essentially I have data with a single date column, and the end date is the next rows start date, but only if its of a certain type. The last row should just use the same start/end.

Open to any other ideas on how to do this also!

Example Data

```
Start   Field
2018-05-22T19:03:30+0000    Product
2018-05-22T19:09:30+0000    Size
2018-05-22T19:09:30+0000    Category
2018-05-22T19:25:39+0000    Product
2018-05-22T19:42:41+0000    Size
2018-05-22T20:57:30+0000    Category

# First Shift
df['End'] = df.loc[df['Field'].isin(['Product', 'Category'])]['Start'].shift(periods=-1)

# Update last row  
shift_rows = df.loc[df['Field'].isin(['Product', 'Category'])]
df.iloc[-1, shift_rows.columns.get_loc('End')] = shift_rows.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Start')] 

# Second shift        
df['End'] = df.loc[df['Field'].isin(['Size'])['Start'].shift(periods=-1)

# Update last row
shift_rows = df.loc[df['Field'].isin(['Size'])]
df.iloc[-1, shift_rows.columns.get_loc('End')] = shift_rows.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Start')]
```

Expected Output

```
Start   Field   End
2018-05-22T19:03:30+0000    Product 2018-05-22T19:09:30+0000
2018-05-22T19:09:30+0000    Size    2018-05-22T19:42:41+0000
2018-05-22T19:09:30+0000    Category    2018-05-22T19:25:39+0000
2018-05-22T19:25:39+0000    Product 2018-05-22T20:57:30+0000
2018-05-22T19:42:41+0000    Size    2018-05-22T19:42:41+0000
2018-05-22T20:57:30+0000    Category    2018-05-22T20:57:30+0000
```

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: @coldspeed Apologies, I have added an expected output! Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I could split out multiple dataframes then rejoin them, but that seems like a bit of a copout!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea could be to create a column Field_group having a number for different group of field. With your sample:

```
df['Field_group'] = df['Field'].apply(lambda field: 1 if field in ['Product', 'Category'] else 2)
```

If you have more than 2 groups of field, you can something like:

```
def associate_group_number (field):
    if field in ['Product', 'Category']: return 1
    if field in ['Size','blabla']: return 2
    if field in ['blo','bli','blu']: return 3
df['Field_group'] = df['Field'].apply(associate_group_number)
```

Now that you have group number, you can use `groupby` and `shift` to create the column 'End' such as:

```
df['End'] = df.groupby('Field_group')['Start'].shift(-1)
```

And because you want to fill the last row of `End` of each group with the time corresponding at this row in `Start` (if I understood well), you can use `fillna`:

```
df['End'] = df['End'].fillna(df['Start'])
```

You can even add the `.fillna(df['Start'])` after `shift(-1)` of the previous line of code to do it in one line, it works (here it was to explain)

Finally, you can drop the column created with:

```
df = df.drop('Field_group',1)
```

Comment: I will give this a whirl, it seems very similar to what I was doing before, but I am guessing the groupby will only apply End to the rows in that group? The fillna option is a great idea!

Comment: That actually worked really well :) Only thing I need to work out is that End is created as dtype datetime64[ns], but I need datetime64[ns, UTC]. I think I should be able to convert with datetime. Thank you!!

Comment: For anyone else coming here the date change was easy as 
   
    .astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]')

Comment: @BobSmith indeed, the method `groupby` can be seen as multiple `isin` at the same time , so you apply the `shift` to each group as you wanted but at once. And `shift` was the good way to achieve your goal :)

Comment: @BobSmith please consider accepting the anwser as it solves your problem :)

Comment: Done! Thanks so much for your help. Indeed groupby is powerful, I didn't think it would operate like that across each group, so it is amazing that it does!!